# assigning role to user in apex leading to an error

Tags: apex, user, dml

I am trying to assign role to a user which i created and thats when I am getting this error : First exception on row 0 with id 0051k000008ykexAAA; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

```
UserRole role = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole where Name = 'CEO'];
        User accountOwner = [select Id,UserRoleId from User where Username = 'newuser147@example.com'];
        accountOwner.UserRoleId = role.Id;
        update accountOwner;
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code. Is there some trigger or flow or any automation on User object which it is invoking and causing this error. Can you check those or deactivate  those and try the same code.

Comment: Is this being performed on a scratch org? If so, the standard roles are broken on a scratch org and you need to create your own.